# Can device sleep before foreground service?

Tags: android, android-service, wakelock

I know that previously we needed to use `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` to ensure that between receiver `onReceive` and service `onHandleIntent` the device doesn't fall back asleep.

Now Google seems to have deprecated `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` because it's not "correct" to start a service from a receiver anymore.

One thing I'm doing is to start a foreground service from a high priority FCM notification. This is completely valid under the new background execution rules. But since `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` is deprecated, does that mean `startForegroundService` guarantees that device stays awake long enough between `onReceive` and `onHandleIntent`'s wakelock? Or should I just hold a wakelock manually in the receiver and send it to the service to release?

Answer (score 0):

> Does that mean startForegroundService guarantees that device stays
>   awake long enough between onReceive and onHandleIntent's wakelock?

No.

> Or should I just hold a wakelock manually in the receiver and send it
>   to the service to release?

You can request partial wakelock in `onCreate()` of your service as follows:

```
private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    final PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK_TAG);
    ...
}
```

Remember to release the wakelock after usage or in onDestroy() as follows:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();      
    if (wakeLock.isHeld()) {
        wakeLock.release();
    }
}
```

Google recommends to avoid usage of wakelock since it could drain user's battery. There are several APIs available for variety of use-cases. Based on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/wakelock#best_practices), you can consider following alternatives:

> - If your app is performing long-running HTTP downloads, consider using DownloadManager.
> - If your app is synchronizing data from an external server, consider creating a sync adapter.
> - If your app needs to execute background tasks at regular intervals, consider using JobScheduler or Firebase JobDispatcher. For information
>     on triggering tasks at specific intervals, see [Intelligent
>     Job-Scheduling.](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling)

Comment: So it's guaranteed that receiver 's wakelock will overlap with service's `onCreate` method such that the device doesn't fall asleep?

Comment: @rcell AFAIK, its not mandatory to request wakelock in the receiver. Using it inside ForegroundService would suffice.